# Update options of searchGrid when adding rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, search, jqgrid

I'm facing a problem : I'd like to update my select options when I add a rule in my searchGrid box.

Here is the context :

I have a grid with a dynamic multicolumn model. For each column, I set search option properly. I added a search button down my grid to open a new search box with multipleSearch:true. I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3 / JavaScript / Jqgrid 4.4.1

Problem : I want to make a field searchable only once. So I'm looking how to trigger buildSelect on my advanced searching.

AfterRedraw function is not what I'm looking for, because we can only handle values once they're built.

First time :

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="Data.0">AGENCY_CODE</option>
<option value="Data.1">Data1</option>
<option value="Data.2">Data2</option>
<option value="Data.3">Data3</option>
</select>
```

When I click on add rule I want :

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="Data.1">Data1</option>
<option value="Data.2">Data2</option>
<option value="Data.3">Data3</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas ?

Problem solved ! It's a little tricky (and to me really ugly ...)

```
var searchSelect = function(select) {
    if (select.length == 1) {
        return select;
    }

    var tmpSelect = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < select.length; i ++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < select[i].options.length; j++) {
            if (select[i].options[j].value == select[0].options[select[0].selectedIndex].value) {
                select[i].options[j].remove();
            }
        }
        tmpSelect.push(select[i]);
    }

    tmpSelect = searchSelect(tmpSelect);
    for (i = 0; i < tmpSelect.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < select[0].options.length; j++) {
            if (select[0].options[j].value == tmpSelect[i].options[tmpSelect[i].selectedIndex].value) {
                select[0].options[j].remove();
            }
        }
    }

    return select;
}

searchSelect($(this).find("table.group td.columns>select"));
```